# Python for loop only executes once when looping csv file

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to python and am having trouble with a small script.

The for loop as defined currently only runs once.

Here's the code (there's 8 elements in each line):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

def string_to_xml(string):
    entries = string.split(',')
    result = "<item>\n"
    result += "\t<distributor>" + entries[0] + "</distributor>\n"
    result += "\t<number>" + entries[1] + "</number>\n"
    result += "\t<description>" + entries[2] + "</description>\n"
    result += "\t<brand>" + entries[3] + "</brand>\n"
    result += "\t<casesize>" + entries[4] + "</casesize>\n"
    result += "\t<unitsize>" + entries[5] + "</unitsize>\n"
    result += "\t<caseprice>" + entries[6] + "</caseprice>\n"
    result += "\t<unitprice>" + entries[7] + "</unitprice>\n"
    result += "</item>"
    return result

with open("input.csv") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        print string_to_xml(line)
```

Like this, it only prints the result of calling string_to_xml once. If I change the statement in the for loop to this:

```
for line in csvfile:
    print line
```

It correctly prints every line of the file.

Why does calling my function string_to_xml cause the loop to only run once?

edit: Here's the first two lines of my csv file if this helps:

```
BIRITE,130405,Steak Sauce,Kraft,24,5oz,43.96,1.83
BIRITE,441045,Anchovy Filet,Maria,12,13oz,51.83,4.32
```

Comment: I'm not using this to actually create valid code, just snippets that I can put into a larger file so I don't have to do it by hand. Difficult to explain in this context, but an xml parser is unnecessary at the moment.

Comment: Yeah IDK why I changed it here but in my code I used "with open as." And changing the method to just "return string" makes it behave as normal.. I don't get why though. I'll edit my question to include everything.

Comment: Works perfectly for me! Any particular reason you used ; on the line doing the split?

Comment: Nope, I keep getting mixed up between languages.. PHP, objc, java, etc. I'll take it out

Comment: Can you test one thing- print line,string_to_xml(line) inside the for loop and then post the results

Comment: `print repr(line), repr(string_to_xml(line))` is a little better than `print line` because it'll make it easier to see the line endings.

Comment: running with `-tt` yields the same result. Changing the print statement to `print line,string_to_xml(line)` prints the line then the generated xml, but only once.. I'm lost. The generated xml is correct, too.

Comment: I get the right answer. It is here: http://pastebin.com/SxiACUpJ    Can you delete the .pyc file corresponding to this script and test again?

Comment: Okay, after `for line in csvfile:`, add `print len(line.split(',')), repr(line[-5:])`.  Maybe (as I hinted earlier) the line endings aren't what you think they are, and so it's getting the entire thing in one line.

Comment: You're using a python installed in /usr/local/bin; is it a custom build?  I'd be curious to see your PYTHON* variables:  `env | grep PYTHON`.  Also whether using `python -E` makes a difference.  And of course the output from `python -V`.

Comment: `print len(line.split(',')), repr(line[-5:])` prints `6311, '0.11'`, 0.11 is the last element in the last line of my input file.

Comment: Your code works fine for me too. Python 2.7.3 on Windows.

Comment: Well, that's why it's only printing one line: there *is* only one line in your file.

Comment: I don't know what a .pyc file is, and @DavidPope I'm developing on a remote linux server, so possible that line is incorrect? Sorry everyone, this is literally the first python script I've ever written.

Comment: You won't have pyc file if you are just executing the file from the command line.

Comment: @DSM I'm not sure why that would be the case, if I open up the .csv file in TextEdit all of the data are on separate lines. Is python not interpreting the newline or something?

Comment: As @DSM is hinting, this is probably a file encoding problem.  Can you show the output of `head -2 input.csv | xxd` ?

Comment: Try replace your open call with `open("input.csv","U")`

Comment: @Eric: I don't use Windows, so I'm not as familiar with how the defaults work there, but that's why `len(line.split(','))` is 6311 and not 8; it's getting it all in one big line.  Listen to whoever is offering encoding advice who sounds like they know what they're talking about. :^)

Comment: `head -2 input.csv | xxd` prints some weird binary data.. Looks like you're right with the file encoding thing, I guess. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `0000000: 4249 5249 5445 2c31 3330 3430 352c 5374  BIRITE,130405,St
0000010: 6561 6b20 5361 7563 652c 4b72 6166 742c  eak Sauce,Kraft,
0000020: 3234 2c35 6f7a 2c34 332e 3936 2c31 2e38  24,5oz,43.96,1.8` is what the head command prints out

Comment: @WinstonEwert: can't we get away with just knowing what the line endings are?  Probably `print repr(line[line.find("1.83"):][:10])` would show it (unfortunately the xxd output just misses it.)

Comment: @WinstonEwert You got it, that fixed it. Please submit that as an answer so I can give you credit. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `open('input.csv', "U")` to open the file.

The "U" tells python to use the universal newlines feature. This allows python to automatically detect what kind of newlines are being used. The problem is that different platforms do newlines differently.

You may want to figure out why you've got strange newlines. You can easily work around the issue here but it could come back and be a pain later.

Comment: This 100% fixed it. Thank you. I was moving this file around between Excel & TextEdit on a Mac to a Linux server, so that must be where it came from. Would have never figured this out without you!

Answer (score 1):

NB: Done on a Linux Machine

Since this code seems to run for other people, lets create a CSV and then run the same code again on it, which shall clarify if it is an encoding issue.

```
a=open('test.csv','wb')
a.write("BIRITE,130405,Steak Sauce,Kraft,24,5oz,43.96,1.83\n"+
    "BIRITE,441045,Anchovy Filet,Maria,12,13oz,51.83,4.32\n")
a.close()

def string_to_xml(string):
    entries = string.split(',')
    result = "<item>\n"
    result += "\t<distributor>" + entries[0] + "</distributor>\n"
    result += "\t<number>" + entries[1] + "</number>\n"
    result += "\t<description>" + entries[2] + "</description>\n"
    result += "\t<brand>" + entries[3] + "</brand>\n"
    result += "\t<casesize>" + entries[4] + "</casesize>\n"
    result += "\t<unitsize>" + entries[5] + "</unitsize>\n"
    result += "\t<caseprice>" + entries[6] + "</caseprice>\n"
    result += "\t<unitprice>" + entries[7] + "</unitprice>\n"
    result += "</item>"
    return result

with open("test.csv") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
       print string_to_xml(line)
```

And the output printed is:

```
<item>
<distributor>BIRITE</distributor>
<number>130405</number>
<description>Steak Sauce</description>
<brand>Kraft</brand>
<casesize>24</casesize>
<unitsize>5oz</unitsize>
<caseprice>43.96</caseprice>
<unitprice>1.83</unitprice>
</item>
<item>
<distributor>BIRITE</distributor>
<number>441045</number>
<description>Anchovy Filet</description>
<brand>Maria</brand>
<casesize>12</casesize>
<unitsize>13oz</unitsize>
<caseprice>51.83</caseprice>
<unitprice>4.32</unitprice>
</item>
```

Comment: This works for me. So there must be something wrong with my .csv file. Is it an encoding thing as some other users suggested in the comments? All of the lines in my file are just like those two.